# How do I maintain work inside drupal containers for working in teams?

Tags: php, docker, drupal

I am new to Drupal and just looking for some help getting my dev environment going and using best practices.

So I have a working container with drupal, mariadb, drush etc... so after installing Drupal with the installer, I install themes and such however it seems if I drop the container I lose all my work. How could I ever work in a team then? How do I keep that work? Do I use git inside the container and pull and push from within?

As far as I'm aware, work inside the container does not necessarily reflect into my local working directory.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know about dupral but generally in docker you would mount a folder from your local filesystem where docker is running when you start the container. The data in the "/your/local/folder" will be accessible both in the container and in your local filesystem. It'll also survive a restart of the container.

```
docker run -d \
-v </your/local/folder>:</folder in container>:z \
<your image>
```

The trick will be to identify the data in the container you want on your local filesystem.

Look here for different alternative ways to handle persistent data in docker:
https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/

Comment: To add to this. The mounted filesystem (which would contain your drupal) would be be a it's own git repository. [Config of the drupal site](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/configuration-management) could be pushed to this repository the normal drupal 8 way.

Answer (score -1):

I can highly recommend you Lando for Drupal 8.
SEE: https://docs.devwithlando.io/tutorials/drupal8.html

It's a free, open-source, cross-platform, local development environment and DevOps tool built on Docker container technology.

Comment: This does not answer the question